# Does f'(x)g'(x)=0 for every x imply f=const. or g=const.?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

f,g are smooth functions of x in R.

f=const. or g=const. is obviously solution to this equation. I wonder if there exists a function which somewhere f'=0 and g'≠0 and otherwhere g'=0. f'≠0. It seems to be against to the smoothness of f and g intuitively.

Is this statement true? If it is, how to prove?

Comment: $f'$ being zero on an interval but not on all of $\mathbb{R}$ does not contradict smoothness, but it would contradict analyticity. See, for example, [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Answer (score 1):

If$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&\text{ if }x\geqslant 0\\0&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$and $g(x)=f(-x)$, then $f'(x)g'(x)$ is always equal to $0$, but neither $f$ nor $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Take any smooth functions $\phi,\psi$ such that
$$
\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } x \leq 0\\
1 &\text{ if } x \geq 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } x \geq 0\\
1 &\text{ if } x \leq -1\\
\end{cases}
$$
They exist: for instance, build $\phi$ through a mollifier such as a "[bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)" and set $\psi(x)=\phi(-x)$. Note that $\phi(x)\psi(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Then take $f,g$ to be primitives of $\phi,\psi$.